# Model returning date value as required although it is not null in table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, entity-framework

I have a asp mvc 5 project using entity framework code-first. I created the controllers and views with scaffolding. Although i have not specified in the model that the Due date be [Required] and the item in the table has a value of NOT NULL.

Yet I am still getting this message on the POST

> The DueDate field is required.

The model is really basic

```
 public class Project
    {
      public int ProjectId { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }

      public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
      public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

      public int ClientId { get; set; }
      public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
   }
}
```

This is a Datetime2 datatype using EditorFor

```
<div class="input-group">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DueDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
        <div class="input-group-addon">
                <a href="#"><i class="entypo-calendar"></i></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

It is also using [jquery bootstrap datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), Although i doubt these has any effect on this functionality. Really confused how this field is a required field yet it has not been set as such in any area of the solution or database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal. `DateTime` is a value type meaning that it will always require a value. The model metadeata provider in ASP.NET MVC automatically adds the required attribute to non-nullable data types. You could use a `nullable DateTime`:

```
public class Project
{
      public int ProjectId { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }

      public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
      public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }

      public int ClientId { get; set; }
      public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```